# Is there a way to use an existing Facebook application token when invoking operations via the JS api?

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a hybrid native/HTML iOS app that utilizes Facebook.  Within the app I've authenticated the user via single sign on API and I have a valid auth token.  Within a web view in the, I embed a web component that also utilizes FB (in my case, a Like box and button for our app page).  If I click on the Like button I am forced to authenticate yet again in the context of the browser.  Is there a way for me to utilize the token obtained by the container app within this web view so that a second authentication can be avoided?